# what does this function do in javascript?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make a sliding carousel using jQuery, here is the code, i dont know what exactly this function do?

```
$w.bind('resize.example', function () {
    var nw = $w.width();
    if (nw < 900) {
        nw = 900;
    }

    $c.width(nw * 3);
    $c.parent().width(nw);

}).trigger('resize.example');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using version less than jQuery v1.7 since you're using `bind()` which is deprecated in versions after 1.7.

`$w.bind('resize.example', function () {`

This line binds an event `resize.example` on the `$w` element.
`resize.example` is custom event and I believe `$w` is `window` object wrapped in jQuery.

`}).trigger('resize.example');`

This triggers the event `resize.example`, this is very common. This is used to run the event handler on the page load.

```
var nw = $w.width();
if (nw < 900) {
    nw = 900;
}
```

This code sets the value of `nw` variable `900` if it `width` of `$w` less than `900`.

```
$c.width(nw * 3);
$c.parent().width(nw);
```

This part of code sets the width of `$c` to 3 times of `nw`.
and the width of parent element of `$c` to value of `nw`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Bind a  custom event named 'resize.example' to the $w element
$w.bind('resize.example', function () {

    //Store the $w width in a variable named 'nw'
    var nw = $w.width();

    if (nw < 900) {
        //If nw < 900 --> set the 'nw' var equal to 900
        nw = 900;
    }

    //Set the $c element width equal to 900*3=2700px
    //*** $c is not defined here..
    $c.width(nw * 3);

    //Set the parent of $c equal to 900px
    $c.parent().width(nw);

}).trigger('resize.example');  //Trigger the custom event to execute the function
```